# UICollectionViewFlowLayout Cell with custom anchorPoint reused too soon

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've subclassed a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to achieve a small scaling effect during horizontal scroll. Therefore I had to subclass a `UICollectionViewCell` as well as to change the `layer.anchorPoint` of the cell (my scaling is from the bottom left of the cell rather than from the default center). Now all fine and well except the fact that when I am scrolling horizontally , my cell is reused too soon (I still can see the half cell when it suddenly disappear ).

I have the feeling that collection view still bases its calculations for reusing the cell on the anchor point positioned in the center of the cell...

However , this is my collection view . You can see how the item getting bigger as it reaches the left side of the collection view. This is the scaling I wanted.
[image]

Now here I am scrolling to the left. You can see how the right item became bigger and the left is getting out of the screen.
[image]

And here you see that the left item didn't get off the screen but already dissapeared. Only the right item remeained visible :/
[image]

So what I want is , to make the left item disappear only when it's right boundaries reaching the very left of the screen.Simply saying , to dissapear only when I don't see it anymore.

And here is my code:

```
class SongsCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imgAlbumCover: UIImageView!


override func applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes)

    //we must change the anchor point for propper cells positioning and scaling
    self.layer.anchorPoint.x = 0
    self.layer.anchorPoint.y = 1
}
```

}

Here is the layout itself :

```
class SongsCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func prepareLayout() {
    collectionView?.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal;

    //size of the viewport
    let size:CGSize = self.collectionView!.frame.size;
    let itemWidth:CGFloat  = size.width * 0.7//0.7//3.0;
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

}

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}


override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    let attributes:[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)!

    var visibleRect:CGRect = CGRect()
    visibleRect.origin = self.collectionView!.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size = self.collectionView!.bounds.size;

    for layoutAttributes in attributes {

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(layoutAttributes.frame, rect)) {

            //we must align items to the bottom of the collection view on y axis
            let frameHeight = self.collectionView!.bounds.size.height
            layoutAttributes.center.y = frameHeight
            layoutAttributes.center.x = layoutAttributes.center.x - self.itemSize.width/2

            //find where ite, left x is
            let itemLeftX:CGFloat = layoutAttributes.center.x

            //distance of the item from the left of the viewport
            let distanceFromTheLeft:CGFloat = itemLeftX - CGRectGetMinX(visibleRect)
            let normalizedDistanceFromTheLeft = abs(distanceFromTheLeft) / self.collectionView!.frame.size.width

            //item that is closer to the left is most visible one
            layoutAttributes.alpha = 1 - normalizedDistanceFromTheLeft
            layoutAttributes.zIndex = abs(Int(layoutAttributes.alpha)) * 10;

            //scale items
            let scale =  min(layoutAttributes.alpha + 0.5, 1)
            layoutAttributes.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)

        }

    }

    return attributes;
}

override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    // Snap cells to centre
    var newOffset = CGPoint()
    let layout = collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let width = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing
    var offset = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionView!.contentInset.left

    if velocity.x > 0 {
        //ceil returns next biggest number
        offset = width * ceil(offset / width)
    } else if velocity.x == 0 { //6
        //rounds the argument
        offset = width * round(offset / width)
    } else if velocity.x < 0 { //7
        //removes decimal part of argument
        offset = width * floor(offset / width)
    }
    newOffset.x = offset - collectionView!.contentInset.left
    newOffset.y = proposedContentOffset.y //y will always be the same...
    return newOffset
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.
So as I suspected , the layout was taking an old center into account that is why I had to correct the center of the cell right after changing the anchor point . So my custom cell now looks like this :

```
class SongsCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imgAlbumCover: UIImageView!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    imgAlbumCover.hnk_cancelSetImage()
    imgAlbumCover.image = nil
}

override func applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes)

    //we must change the anchor point for propper cells positioning and scaling
    self.layer.anchorPoint.x = 0
    self.layer.anchorPoint.y = 1

    //we need to adjust a center now
    self.center.x = self.center.x - layoutAttributes.size.width/2
}
```

}

Hope it helps someone